# NSWindow title bar with MTKView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, metal

When I use OpenGL for rendering (in NSOpenGLView), the title bar of NSWindow is OK

See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

but as soon as I attach an MTKView to it (the code I use in the Ouzel engine: https://github.com/elvman/ouzel/blob/master/ouzel/osx/WindowOSX.mm#L143), the title bar becomes dark grey

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I have searched for the flag to disable this behaviour, but with no success. Do you know what causes the title become dark grey and how to disable that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that dark header is caused by changing the background color of NSWindow (_window.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor];). It is weird that the color of the header is being affected by NSWindow's background color only when a Metal view (MTKView) is being attached to it, but it isn't when the same is being done with an OpenGL view (NSOpenGLView).